# Combining contentOffset in an if statement? iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Basically what I am trying to figure out, is how to write the following:

```
//pseudo-code
if (the x value for contentOffset is equal to 
   a figure between, say, 50 and 100) {
   then a specific void is to be executed. 
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question. Do you mean something like `if(contentOffset.x>=50 || contentOffset.x <=100) {}` ? What are you asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CGPoint offsetPoint = myScrollView.contentOffset;
float offset = sqrtf(powf(offsetPoint.x,2)+(powf(offsetPoint.y,2));
if (50 < offset && offset < 100) {
   [self myMethod];
}
```

or if you are only interested in one direction, say vertically,

```
CGFloat offset = myScrollView.contentOffset.y;
```

Comment: `scrollView.contentOffset` is a CGPoint, not a float. ;)

Comment: Mate thats fantastic! Exactly what I was after... just quickly, the code you provided 'if i was only interested in one direction', would that simply replace the first two lines of code in your initial block of code?

Comment: Yes, the line would replace the Pythagorean calculation and be inserted just before the if-statement.